# Android SDK 23+ Permissions in Services

Tags: android

I would like to update my project to SDK 23, but I have different services running in the background to receive data, store them, send etc...

So if I update the project I also have to change the permission requesting. Now I am wondering where the best place to do this is.

Just at the moment received data should be saved?
But this would be pretty abstract for the user, especially if a config file or something needs to be transfered and the user gains nothing noticable from this.

Before starting the service just request all permissions the service requires?
This makes the whole concept absurd because it would be the same as so far...

So thank you for your input!

Comment: "Before starting the service just request all permissions the service requires?" -- probably this is the correct answer. "This makes the whole concept absurd because it would be the same as so far" -- you may wish to explain in greater detail what you mean by this. You might also consider explaining what `dangerous` permissions your service will be needing. Normally, "receive data, store them, send" do not require `dangerous` permissions, except if you are working with arbitrary locations on external storage.

Comment: If I got the concept right, permissions should not be requested before they are really used. That's why i call it absurd, but maybe I'm just wrong at this point.
Im working on a kind of gallery where I need to store the data on external storage that other applications (standard gallery for example) or the user himself can easily access them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I got the concept right, permissions should not be requested before they are really used.

Correct, bearing in mind that the request is part of your user experience and therefore needs to be tied to the UI. Besides, from a technical standpoint, you can only request a permission from an `Activity`.

My general rule of thumb is: postpone requesting the permission until the user takes some positive step that will lead down a code path that requires that permission.

In some apps, that "positive step" is simply launching the app, as the permissions are needed right away. In that case, you check for the permissions in `onCreate()` of your launcher activity.

In other apps, that "positive step" might be the user clicking on an action bar item, or on a nav drawer item, or on a button, or on a `RecyclerView` item, etc. In that case, you can delay asking for the permission until the user clicks that thing, so users who never click it will never have to be asked for the permission.

So, look at when and how your service is started. That will determine what the user's "positive step" is that should be tied into your requesting the needed permissions.

Comment: Ok so I got it right so far.
But then I have to ask: what is the point of this? If users get to many permission requests on application startup, they will ignore them and just accept them - so the effect is nothing better than the one so far with acceptance on installation. It's just more work for us and annoying for the users - isn't it?

Comment: @Agyss: Developers will find ways to deliver value without requesting and requiring permissions in `onCreate()`. Beyond that, just because the user elects to grant you permission does not mean that you will have that permission forever, as the user can retract it via Settings at any point. Offering this sort of permission granularity -- versus the classic "all or nothing" approach -- is really the objective here.